# ValueError: Unknown layer: CRF with pyspark udf

Tags: keras, pyspark

I saved the Keras model with CRF layer as follows:

```
model.save(modelName)
```

and loaded it as below:

```
model= load_model('model.h5',custom_objects={'CRF':CRF,'crf_loss':crf_loss,'crf_accuracy':crf_accuracy})
```

It is working fine when I am using model to predict in python.
But when I am trying to load the model which is being called in function predicts to predict the results and call it as a udf in pyspark then I am getting error:

> " ValueError: Unknown layer: CRF"

```
predict_skills = udf(lambda description: p.predict_s(description))
df_new=df_new.select('a')\
         .withColumn("b", predict_s(col("a")))
```

In order to make the keras with additional CRF layer work in pyspark do  need to do anything additional?

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done outside of udf!

Do this:
[Iterator of Series to Iterator of Series](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html#iterator-of-series-to-iterator-of-series)

```py
@pandas_udf("long")
def predict(iterator: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    # Do initialization with a model
    model = load_model('model.h5',custom_objects={'CRF':CRF,'crf_loss':crf_loss,'crf_accuracy':crf_accuracy})

    for series in iterator:
        # Use that model for whole iterator.
        yield predict_with_model(series, model)

df.select(predict("value")).show()
```